# Interpolate line and profile graph error, not sure how to fix

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst

I am using the "Interpolate Line" tool in 3D Analyst to create a profile using "Profile Graph". However, I get two error windows:

  1.

> Unable to create temporary shapefile

  2.

> To create a profile graph, the selected graphic or feature has to be a
>   3D line. To create a 3D line, use the Interpolate Line tool or Line of
>   Sight tool.

My DEM has been selected.

Workflow:
[image: Location]

[image: Select Interpolate Line]

[image: Select line]

[image: Result following Profile Graph 1]

[image: Result following Profile Graph 1]

Comment: Could you post pictures of your workflow?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are those error wordings exactly what you see?  What were the precise steps that led to the first one?

Comment: @KeaganAllan Have uploaded workflow.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yup exactly as I see, have added workflow.

Comment: I have not come across this error before. So some thoughts...where is the data / mxd saved? Do you have write permissions? How was the "Wtrshd_bathy" raster created? Was it interpolated from input data, or did you convert from a TIN? Is everything projected correctly? Have you tried closing Arc and starting again in a fresh mxd?

Comment: Is the spatial reference of the data frame set? The lower right says metres but that could be assumed. This is kind of strange, I follow your procedure exactly and it works fine for me. There is that weird error about not being able to create a temp shapefile; what is your %temp% and %tmp%? Are they still default? Is that drive full? requiring special permissions?

Comment: ArcGis saves profile graphs in a folder. Try this with everything on saved on hard drive. Outside mxd gdb.

Answer (score 1):

I think @FelixIP is correct here.

Using the 3D analyst toolbar, click "3D Analyst" and then options below. A window will open. Under the "Graph Data" tab there is a box specifying the "Location to save profile graph data:".

Add in you desired location, boom, you've got it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Change the dataframe coordinate system.
- Then, change it back to the original one.